# MySQL: Table structure for a ressource based game

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, mysql-workbench

I'm currently working on a game where we use ressources like: food, wood, stone, copper, etc. I'm having a problem with the structure for my ressources table.

1. A ressource has a: "name" and a "base price".
2. Each guild has a list of ressources (their personal banks of accumulated ressources).
3. Buildings have a cost of creation (a farm cost 10 woods and 2 stones to create).
4. Buildings have a monthly production (a farm produce 4 foods per month).

What is the best way to create my tables in this scenario?

First I went with a simple "Ressources" table with only 3 fields (id, name and basePrice).
Then I made an "Guild_has_ressource" table between "Ressources" and "Guild".
Then it became a mess when I tried to do the same with "Buildings"... There was gonna be way too many tables. There is gotta be an optimal way of doing this.

**EDIT**: Lotan mentionned I needed more details.
My database looks like this:
[Database_v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydP4S.png)
All my ressources are in a single table "Inventaires". I have a strong feeling that it is the wrong way of doing it.
I believe they should be in a table called "Ressources" where they can have their own "name" field and "basePrice".

A guild has ressources in its bank, a building has a construction price and a production income. How can all these 3 field connects to the same Table "Ressources"?

**EDIT2**: After more comments. I tested 2 more options.

1st: https://ibb.co/ZdHYLMT

2nd: https://ibb.co/G3ntdLz

What do you guys think? Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you have to explain a little bit more, why you need SQL tables, which are the porpouse of those tables?

Comment: @Lotan I added new info in the post. Tell me if you still don't understand what I mean. Im new here. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this [image: DB Schema]

It does not feel right, it does not work properly but it's what I managed to do by myself...